# near initialization structure warning

Tags: c

I'm genuinly confused as to why i am having this error. My code compiles fine but i would prefer to have 0 warnings. After searching stackoverflow for a bit no one had the same structure type that i was using. Below is a snippit of my code (these are made up names)

if it helps my MAXCONTACTS is set to 5

```
struct Contact conNum[MAXCONTACTS] =  { { {"Rick", { '\0' }, "Grimes" },
    {11, "Trailer Park", 0, "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
    {"4161112222", "4162223333", "4163334444" } },
  {
    {"Maggie", "R.", "Greene" },
    {55, "Hightop House", 0, "A9A 3K3", "Bolton" },
    {"9051112222", "9052223333", "9053334444" } },
  {
    {"Morgan", "A.", "Jones" },
    {77, "Cottage Lane", 0, "C7C 9Q9", "Peterborough"},
    {"7051112222", "7052223333", "7053334444" } },
  {
    {"Sasha", {'\0'}, "Williams" },
    {55, "Hightop House", 0, "A9A 3K3", "Bolton"},
    {"9052223333", "9052223333", "9054445555" } },
};
```

edit: here is my structure declaration

```
// Structure type Name declaration
struct Name {
char firstName[31];
char middleInitial[7];
char lastName[36];
};


struct Address {
int streetNumber;
int apartmentNumber;
char street[41];
char postalCode[8];
char city[41];
};



struct Numbers {
char cell[11];
char home[11];
char business[11];
};


struct Contact {

struct Name name;
struct Address address;
struct ``Numbers numbers;

};
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the full definition of `struct Contact` (any any other nested fields) for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: What is MAXCONTACTS current value ?

Comment: Plus, what is the exact warning you're getting ?

Comment: BTW: `{ '\0' }` You propbably mean `""` here  (or NULL)

Comment: @wildplasser isnt \0 basically the same as null? After trying to change, it resulted in another warning,

Comment: @ewowie: The "near initialization" part just tells you that there is a warning at that place. [You should check the entire list of warnings as seen here](https://godbolt.org/z/yK0EmX), i.e. `initialization of 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast`, `(near initialization for 'conNum[0].address.apartmentNumber')`. The "near" part is just a continuation of the previous message. Btw, it's easy to change the order of struct fields and introduce errors this way, so either use designated initializers, or create actual functions for initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct Address` contains two `int` fields followed by two `char` arrays:

```
struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    int apartmentNumber;
    char street[41];
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};
```

but you don't initialize them in that order:

```
{11, "Trailer Park", 0, "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
```

Unless you use named initializers, fields must be specified in order.  Put the street number first, then the apartment number, *then* the street:

```
{11, 0, "Trailer Park", "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
```

Do the same with the other three.

Comment: thank you so much. Its always the smallest errors that can make you go crazy

Comment: Named initializers are also called [Designated Initializers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers).

Answer (score 1):

```
{11, "Trailer Park", 0, "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
```

this initialization is for

```
struct Address {
   int streetNumber;
   int apartmentNumber;
   char street[41];
   char postalCode[8];
   char city[41];
};
```

As you see you are trying to initialize `"Trailer Park"` to `int apartmentNumber;`.

That is why you are getting warning.

---

Thus change the definition of structure to

```
struct Address {
   int streetNumber;
   char street[41];
   int apartmentNumber;
   char postalCode[8];
   char city[41];
};
```

At only one place

or

change the initialization sequence like below in all the places.

```
   {11,  0, "Trailer Park", "A7A 2J2", "King City" },
```